# Array of objects properties become NaN between function calls in Html Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nan

This code is done in HTML javascript.
The following functions (`placero()` and `runro()`) are called in that order. `placero()` seems to initialize the `x`s and `y`s of the object list correctly, but by the time the first line of `runro()` is called, all of the `x`s and `y`s have become `NaN`.
The goal of the code was to make a program that creates rooms and connects them with corridors. Previous steps have inititalized the rooms and corridor layout, but the job of `placero()` is to place each room somewhere random on the map.
the code is as follows:

runm does all the initial setting code(such as the room member initialization) and does all the other work before placero(). I have been clicking the buttons in the intended order(sequentially), so that shouldnt be the problem.

```js
var roomes = new Array(0);


function randIntBetween(min, max) { // min and max included  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


//before any function calls, rooms is initialized as follows(well after the input has been entered, in most cases):
roomMax = document.getElementById("inp1").value; //this is the inputted number of rooms being made
for (var k = 0; k < roomMax; k++) {
  var obj = {
    ind: k,
    x: -1,
    y: -1,
    neighb: Array(0)
  }
  roomes.push(obj);
}


//then some work is done, placing the indexes of other rooms in the neighbors array in each room.
//none of the in-between code edits x or y.
function placero() {
  for (var kis = 0; kis < roomes.length; kis++) {
    var x = randIntBetween(5, mapX - 5); //get a random x and y for room position
    var y = randIntBetween(5, 5);
    roomes[kis].x = x;
    roomes[kis].y = y;
  }
  console.log(roomes); //prints a correct array
}


function runro() {
  console.log(roomes); //prints an incorrect array
  var iterCount = 2;
  //this code aims to place rooms closer to their neighbors, by averaging a rooms position with that of its neighbors and moving it half the way in that direction.
  for (var ki = 0; ki < iterCount; ki++) { //for each iteration in which the rooms are moved,
    for (var kt = 0; kt < roomes.length; kt++) { //for each room
      var coun = NeighbCount(roomes[kt]); //get number of neighbors(will be used for averageing)
      console.log(coun);
      var sumx = 0;
      var sumy = 0;
      for (var km = 0; km < coun; km++) { //for each neighbor,
        sumx = sumx + roomes[roomes[kt].neighb[km]].x; //add its position to the sum position
        sumy = sumy + roomes[roomes[kt].neighb[km]].y;
      }
      sumx = sumx / coun; //then divide by number of neighbors to get new position
      sumy = sumy / coun;
      console.log(sumx + " " + roomes[kt].x); //troubleshooting
      console.log(sumy + " " + roomes[kt].y);
      roomes[kt].x = sumx / 2 + roomes[kt].x / 2; //setting new positions
      roomes[kt].y = sumy / 2 + roomes[kt].y / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" id="inp1" name="inp1"><br>
</div>
<button onclick="runm()">Make room map</button>
<button onclick="placero()">place rooms</button>
<button onclick="runro()">Make rooms</button>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant html to the snippet. `roomMax` will be a string, but you need a `number`. Use `valueAsNumber`, or, when the input has the `type="number"` atttribute set, use `parseInt()` to parse the value.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: runm is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the error because `roomMax` is of string type and not number type. To solve this, make the following modifications to your code:

```js
roomMax = parseInt(document.getElementById("inp1").value);
```

The value from an `input` will always be a string. The code above changes the type.

Look through your code to see if you have any similar mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I did not realize that parseInt existed, much lass that it was required for that sort of thing.

Comment: For inputs of type number you can use `valueAsNumber` so `document.getElementById("inp1").valueAsNumber`. Also always provide a radix for `parseInt` it doesn't default to 10 `parseInt(document.getElementById("inp1").value, 10)` (less important in recent implementations)